# How does Frequency-division multiplexing deals with overlaps?

Tags: frequency, multiplexer, dma, networking

As I understand it, FDM uses separate frequency for each channel, thus A will transmit data, for instance, every two seconds and B every three seconds.

But, what will be delivered on the wire in the overlapping times, after 6, 12, 18 seconds in my example?

Does the multiplexer sends data from both channels? If so, how could someone distinguish between the senders? And if they are marked, what's the point of the frequency here?

Comment: You seem to be confusing FDM (frequency-division multiplexing) with TDM (time-division multiplexing). FDM assigns each user a separate frequency band, which can be used in parallel. TDM assigns each user a time slot, and these cannot overlap. With FDM, you get 100% usage of a relatively narrow band of frequencies, while with TDM, you get to use a very wide bandwidth for only some of the time.

Comment: Why not? If A's frequency is one occurrence per 2 seconds and B's frequency is one occurrence per 3 seconds, every six seconds their occurrences will overlap, not?

Comment: No, that's not what FDM means. It means that user A gets to use, say, 900-904 MHz, while user B gets to use 904-908 MHz. Each one can use his assigned frequency band continuously.

Comment: In FDM, A and B have different signal frequencies, not different repetition rates. A and B will always be signaling, not every 2 or 3 seconds. Since (for example), A might have a signal frequency of 1 MHz and B 2 MHz, the two frequencies do not "overlap". Commercial radio and TV are examples of FDM, and with a little care the signals do not interfere.

Comment: How could they interfere, by the way, if the frequency is different?

Comment: That is, in fact, the whole point of FDM. What is your question?

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast was using the example of commercial radio as an FDM system. local radio stations in different parts of the country could be assigned the same frequency. but because they are not in line of sight they do not interfere. sources in any local area do not overlap. That is the 'with a little care' he is referring to.

Comment: @Icy - Good on yer, mate.

Comment: I'm sorry that maybe I ask again, but it seems that some of the physical picture is not clear to me. It is not clear to me why different frequencies can not overlap/interfere. As I understand it, frequency is occurrences per unit of time. And, if the amplitude of the waves is the same, why should not there maybe times when the signals overlapping, in their picks.

Comment: It works fine for radio and TV. It works fine for listening to music or speech. It will work fine for waves in any linear medium. Your concern will only apply to non-linear media.

Answer (score 1):

As some people said in the comments, you are misunderstanding what frequency division multiplexing means.

FDM does not mean that each channel sends data at different times (or with different intervals separating chunks of data being sent).

FDM means that each channel sends data by using a different band of the frequency spectrum.

In a simple example, channel *n* might send a message \$m_n(t)\$ by sending a signal

$$v_n(t)=A\left(1+m_n(t)\right)\sin\left(2\pi{}f_n t\right)$$

Notice that this signal doesn't turn off and on at different times. It is continuously present.

Again, using a simple example rather than a practical one, each of the different signals could be picked out at the receiver using a bandpass filter centered around \$f_n\$, allowing each of the signals in the system to be recovered independently.